# Navigation Property returns null?

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

```
class Topic {
   public int TopicId {get;set;}
   public virtual ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set; }
   public Post FirstPost { 
      get {
         return this.Posts.OrderBy(p=> p.PostedDate).FirstOrDefault();
      }
   }
}

class Post {
    public int PostId {get;set; }
    public int TopicId {get;set;}
    public DateTime PostedDate {get;set;}

    public virtual Topic Topic {get;set;}
}


var query = Database.Forums.Where(p=> p.Id == id).Select(p=> new  {
   p.Title,
   Topics = p.Topics.OrderByDescending(p=> p.LastPostedDate).Select(t=> new  {
       t.TopicId,
       t.FirstPost.PostId
   })
}).ToList();
```

When I run this query, t.FirstPost is null even though the topic does have posts in the database. Is there a way to do this using navigational properties instead of using query syntax and joins?

Comment: Shouldn't this be like 
`public Post FirstPost { 
      get {
         return this.Posts.OrderBy(p=> p.PostedDate).FirstOrDefault();
      }
   }`

this.Posts instead of this.Post

Comment: Oops, you're right...I just removed most of the code for brevity and there are some typos.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to update code from this.Post to this.Posts like this

```
public Post FirstPost { 
      get {
         return this.Posts.OrderBy(p=> p.PostedDate).FirstOrDefault();
      }
   }
```

Comment: Put a breakpoint inside get method and check if this.Posts has any post entities

Answer (score 0):

In general avoid using not mapped properties in LINQ to Entities query. They cannot be translated to SQL, and even that EF Core supports client side evaluation, accessing the navigation properties is problematic since they are not loaded yet at the time evaluation occurs.

You can use navigations properties inside LINQ to Entities query (which is actually preferable over explicit joins), but with explicit *expression*, i.e. not hidden behind unmapped property:

```
var query = Database.Forums.Where(f => f.Id == id).Select(f => new
{
   f.Title,
   Topics = f.Topics.OrderByDescending(t => t.LastPostedDate).Select(t => new
   {
       t.TopicId,
       FirstPostId = Posts.OrderBy(p => p.PostedDate).Select(p => (int?)p.PostId).FirstOrDefault(),
   })
}).ToList();
```

(not sure what `LastPostedDate` is - it's not shown in the posted model, and hope is not another unmapped property. But you get the idea).